# Why do hypotensive patients receive oxygen therapy?

Tags: oxygenation, hypoxia

I read that the American College of Chest Physicians recommended the use of oxygen therapy in several occasions one of which was hypotension if systolic blood pressure was less than 100 mm Hg.

I'm wondering why that is, does oxygen help in returning blood pressure to normal? What's the science behind it?

Comment: This question would be substantially improved by providing a link to the recommendation itself. "I read" cannot easily be verified or considered in context.

Comment: Consider that what you read didn't say supplemental oxygen would raise blood pressure. So how else might it help?

Comment: But @IanCampbell is right: you need to link to what you read, at a minimum.